# Pandas - Count number of elements in each series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
ID,Variation_price
1,{X:1, Y:2, Z:3}    
2,{}
3,{X:5, W:6}
```

How can I count the number of items for each ID to get this result:

```
1: 3
2: 0
3: 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us do

```
df['count_n']=df['Variation'].str.len()
```

If the data type is string

```
df['count_n']=df['Variation'].str.count(':')
```

Comment: I just want to count the items, not every string. Your code's results for ID 1 is 13. Do you have another way?

Comment: @Harper your dict is just a string . check the update

Comment: @YOandBEN_W, Thank you for sharing nice command sir, could you please do let me know how we created dataframe here(since 2nd element is a dictionary), I was trying to create it but was getting an error.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 check ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the length of a dictionary.

```
df['count_n'] = 0.0
for i in range(len(df)):
    df.loc[i, 'count_n']=len(df.loc[i,'Variation'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `len()` to get the number of the elements per list.
Example:

```
for index_, row_ in iterrow(tables)
    print(len(row_))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Variation column is string type:

```
import ast
df.set_index('ID').Variation.apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(len)
```

If your Variation column is dict type:

```
df.set_index('ID').Variation.apply(len)
```